# Code compiles despite of taking address of Wrong Data Types

Tags: c++, constants

```
#include <iostream>
#define n 255

using namespace std;


int main()
{
int i=n;
int *ptr=&i;
int const *ptr_1=&i;
const int *ptr_2=&i;
const int * const ptr_3=&i;
}
```

Why does this Code Compile in Visual C++, Dev C++ and G++?
Link to [- Ideone -](http://www.ideone.com/qpBTi)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does compile, because all those pointers ether don't change `const`-qualification of the variable access or enforce the qualification, but none of them tries to loosen the qualification.

For example:

```
const int var;
int* address = &var; //illegal - tries to remove const
```

would try to get non-const access to a const variable and that's illegal, but

```
int var;
const int* address = &var; //legal - only adds const
```

tries to get const access to a non-const variable and that's legal since a non-const variable does allow const-only access.

Comment: Shouldn't it throw an error, when a pointer-to-constant-integer takes the address of an int which is not const?

Comment: @Acme: Why? If I can *read and write* it implies I can *read*.

Comment: @Acme Adding const-ness never requires an explicit cast. Removing const is what can be dangerous.

Comment: @Acme: No, it should not. Pointer to constant int means you can't change value of the target variable *via this pointer* only, not that it may not change at all.

Answer (score 3):

Because there's nothing wrong with it?

Same types on both side: `int *ptr=&i;`

More const, perfectly ok: `int const *ptr_1=&i;`

Exactly the same as above line: `const int *ptr_2=&i;`

More const, perfectly ok: `const int * const ptr_3=&i;`

You can always make a variable **more** const.

```
int const * i;
int * j = i;
```

The above makes j *less* const and isn't valid.

4.4/1: (Covers `int *` to `int const *`)

> An rvalue of type “pointer to cv1 T”
>   can be converted to an rvalue of type
>   “pointer to cv2 T” if “cv2 T” is more
>   cv-qualified than “cv1 T.”

Answer (score 0):

You are probably wondering why the value can be made `const` when taking the address.

This is legal and is known as *`const` promotion* in C++ parlance.

Note that only *one level* of `const` promotion may happen – that is, a `int**` may be promoted to `int* const*` but not to `int const**` (the `const` would have to “move” two places to the left).

Answer (score 0):

C++ allows you to create pointers to the variables created on the stack. Thus, there is nothing wrong with this code. Moreover, it is often used to pass parameters to functions such as WINAPI.

If the question about the semantics of pointers then the answer is a full-fledged.
For example:

```
int * ptr; //pointer to a variable. Pointer and the variable can be changed.
int const * ptr; //a pointer to the constant variable, a pointer can be changed, the variable can not.
const int * ptr; //same as above.
const int * const ptr_3; //the most interesting section, a const pointer to const variable.
```

Just remember that the modifiers before * refer to the variable, after it - to the pointer.